# How to pass a string to a command that expects a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Suppose a program `cook` takes one argument: the pathname of a text file containing the recipe of the food to cook. Suppose I wish to call this program from within a `bash` script, also suppose I already have the recipe in a string variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

the_recipe="$(cat << EOF
wash cucumbers
wash knife
slice cucumbers
EOF
)"

cook ...  # What should I do here? It expects a file, but I only have a string.
```

How can I pass the recipe to the command when it expects a filename argument?

I thought about creating a temporary file just for the purpose passing a file, but I wish to know if there are alternative ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Similar: [Using data read from a pipe instead than from a file in command options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16990/170373)

Comment: The duplicate question talks about data arriving on a pipe. This question talks about having data in a variable. The code in this question may trivially be reformulated by adding `printf '%s\n' "$the_recipe" | cook`, and this would make it an exact duplicate.  I chose to mark this as a dupe of the other as it was older and as the other was more generally formulated from the start.

Comment: I adapted this excellent question to the Windows case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000360/how-to-pass-a-string-to-a-windows-cmd-that-expects-a-file-argument If anyone has a clue about Windows, please consider answering it.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. Though they are related.

Answer (score 75):

You can use the "fake" filename `/dev/stdin` which represents the standard input.

So execute this:

```
echo "$the_recipe" | cook /dev/stdin
```

The echo command and the pipe sends the contents of the specified variable to the standard input of the next command `cook`, and that opens the standard input (as a separate file descriptor) and reads that.

Comment: Is this method limited to commands that take only one argument? If `cook` takes two file arguments, and I have `the_recipe1` and `the_recipe2` (both of which are string variables), will this method still work?

Comment: @Flux You can do it with `/dev/fd` but that's beyond the scope of your initial question. But I think you'll find examples of that in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-descriptors

Comment: This is not 100% portable, though it does come pretty close in practice: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36403/91565

Comment: Very good, very simple.

Answer (score 58):

One other way to use the process-substitution feature of the `bash` shell causes a FIFO to be created under `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`, or uses a named file descriptor (`/dev/fd/*`), depending on the operating system. The substitution syntax (`<(cmd)`) is replaced by the name of the FIFO or FD, and the command inside it is run in the background.

```
cook <(printf '%s\n' "${the_recipe}")
```

The command `cook` now reads the content of the variable as if it were available in a file.

This could also be used for more than one input file:

```
cook <(printf '%s\n' "${the_1st_recipe}") <(printf '%s\n' "${the_2nd_recipe}")
```

Comment: Alternatively, `cat <<<"$the_recipe"` inside the process substitution.

Comment: Note that process substitution is a ksh feature (now also supported by zsh and bash). Chances are `cook` will expect a text file, so you should probably make it `'%s\n'` instead of `'%s'`. See also `<(<<<$the_recipe)` in `zsh`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when running a command through `sudo`. "error: Failed to open file '/dev/fd/63': No such file or directory"

Comment: `cat <<<"$the_recipe"` works find on bash. And probably more efficient due to not starting another process.

Answer (score 32):

It depends on the application's capabilities. It may or may not insist on a named file, and it may or may not insist on a seekable file.

#### Anonymous pipe

Some applications just read input from anywhere. Typically they default to reading from standard input. If you have the data in a string and you want to pass it to the application's standard input, there are a few ways. You can pass the information via a pipe:

```
printf '%s' "$the_recipe" | cook     # passes $the_recipe exactly
printf '%s\n' "$the_recipe" | cook   # passes $the_recipe plus a final newline
```

Don't use `echo` here because depending on the shell, it might mangle backslashes.

If the application insists on a file argument, it might accept `-` to mean standard input. This is a common convention, but not systematic.

```
printf '%s\n' "$the_recipe" | cook -
```

If the application needs an actual file name, pass `/dev/stdin` to mean standard input.

```
printf '%s\n' "$the_recipe" | cook /dev/stdin
```

For some applications, even this is not enough: they need a file name with certain properties, for example with a given extension, or they need a file name in a writable directory where they create temporary files. In such cases, you generally need a temporary file, although sometimes a named pipe is enough.

#### Named pipe

It's possible to give a pipe a name. I mention this for completeness, but it's rarely the most convenient way. It does avoid getting the data on disk. It's suitable if the application needs a file with constraints on the name, but doesn't need the file to be seekable.

```
mkfifo named.pipe
printf '%s\n' "$the_recipe" >named.pipe & writer=$!
cook named.pipe
rm named.pipe
wait "$writer"
```

(Error checking omitted.)

#### Temporary file

If the application needs a *seekable* file, you need to create a temporary file. A seekable file is one where the application can go back and forth, reading arbitrary portions at a time. A pipe doesn't allow this: it needs to be read from start to finish, in sequence, without ever going backwards.

Bash, ksh and zsh have a convenient syntax to pass a string as input via a temporary file. Note that they always append a newline to the string (even if there's already one).

```
cook <<<"$the_recipe"
```

With other shells, or if you want to control which directory contains the temporary file, you need to create the temporary file manually. Most unices provide a [`mktemp` utility](https://man.openbsd.org/mktemp.1) to create the temporary file securely. (Never use something like <strike>`… >/tmp/temp.$$`</strike>! It allows other programs, even running as other users, to hijack the file.) Here's a script that creates a temporary file and takes care of removing it if interrupted.

```
tmp=
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"' EXIT
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; trap "" HUP; kill -INT $$' HUP
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; trap "" INT; kill -INT $$' INT
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; trap "" TERM; kill -INT $$' TERM
tmp=$(mktemp)
printf '%s\n' "$the_recipe" >"$tmp"
cook "$tmp"
```

To choose where to create the temporary file, set the `TMPDIR` environment variable for the `mktemp` call. For example, to create the temporary file in the current directory rather than the default location for temporary files:

```
tmp=$(TMPDIR="$PWD" mktemp)
```

(Using `$PWD` rather than `.` gives you an absolute file name, which means you can safely call `cd` in your script without worrying that `$tmp` will no longer designate the same file.)

If the application needs a file name with a certain extension, you need to create a temporary directory and create a file there. To create the temporary directory, use `mktemp -d`. Again, set the `TMPDIR` environment variable if you want to control where the temporary directory is created.

```
tmp=
trap 'rm -rf "$tmp"' EXIT
trap 'rm -rf "$tmp"; trap "" HUP; kill -INT $$' HUP
trap 'rm -rf "$tmp"; trap "" INT; kill -INT $$' INT
trap 'rm -rf "$tmp"; trap "" TERM; kill -INT $$' TERM
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
printf '%s\n' "$the_recipe" >"$tmp/myfile.ext"
cook "$tmp/myfile.ext"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use a here-doc as input, too (I think you might have to use `<(cat <<END)` or similar; it's years since I've done that).

Comment: in Bash (maybe others?) `cook <<<"$the_recipe"` doesn't create a temporary file. It redirects the string to stdin of `cook`. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings

Comment: @AlexWillmer There are two plausible ways to implement `<<<`: with a temporary file, or with a pipe. I'm not aware of a shell that implements it with a pipe. The bash documentation doesn't specify one way or the other, but empirically, it uses a temporary file. To test this, on Linux (or other Unix variant with `/proc/self/fd`): `bash -c 'ls -lL /proc/self/fd/0 <<<hello'`

Comment: I disagree, just because Linux lists file descriptors of a process in /proc does not mean <<< creates a named temporary file. Try `echo <<<"hello"`, which outputs a blank line. Compare that to `echo <(ls)`, which outputs the path of the named temporary file bash has created, and provided as an argument to `echo` e.g. `/dev/fd/45`.

Comment: @AlexWillmer `/dev/fd/45` is not a path to a temporary file. It's a “magic” symbolic link in the `/proc` filesystem (“magic” in the sense that its behavior is not something you can fully mimic with a symlink that you create yourself). Its existence proves nothing since all file descriptors have such a corresponding file. I'm telling you to look at the path and the file type of the **target** of the symlink (`-L` option to `ls`). This way you can see whether the target is an ordinary file in `/tmp` (which is the case for bash's `<<<`), an anonymous pipe, a named pipe, …

Comment: ........WOW.  Giving this response a serious read, I think I learned more in the last ~10 minutes than I have on the internet in a very long time. Bravo!

Comment: The implementation of `<<<` (and `<<`) was changed in Bash 5.1 (released in December 2020).  The relevant sentence from the release notes is "Here documents and here strings now use pipes for the expanded document if it's smaller than the pipe buffer size, reverting to temporary files if it's larger".

Answer (score 5):

Always check if your version of `cook` supports the argument `-` (dash) as a filename before trying more complicated solutions. If this convention is supported, it tells `cook` to read from the standard input, like so:

```
echo "$the_recipe" | cook -
```

or

```
cook - <<<"$the_recipe"
```